# Storing Android Emoji in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, emoji

We are storing the emoji selected by the users in text body in MySQL. We have the column looks like this

```
`body` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin,
```

Original data : `<div id='mobile-question-style' style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial; color:#333333;\">\uD83D\uDE1D\uD83D\uDE3E\uD83D\uDE3E\uD83D\uDE3A\uD83D\uDE3A\uD83D\uDE1D</div>`

Data in DB : `<div id='mobile-question-style' style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial; color:#333333;">????????????</div>`

But when if fetch it from the Rest API it looks correct : `"body":"<div id='mobile-question-style' style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial; color:#333333;\">\uD83D\uDE1D\uD83D\uDE3E\uD83D\uDE3E\uD83D\uDE3A\uD83D\uDE3A\uD83D\uDE1D</div>",`

Now when I update the question, using Rest API it looses it encoding and showes "????"

Data from endpoint after I update : `"body":"<div id='mobile-question-style' style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial; color:#333333;\">????????????</div>",`

There is special logic when updating the body so does any one knows what is going on here?

Comment: Log exactly every string on the Java side and switch to `utf8mb` in the database.

Comment: Thanks Karol S, I am getting Unknown character set: 'utf8mb' I think we are using < 5.5 of MySQL. Is is safe? I mean we have 5 years worth of production data so can it corrupt the data by converting it to 'utf8mb'

Comment: I cannot guarantee anything. I recommend doing backup before trying to convert anything, and updating MySQL just for security and performance.

Comment: Thanks Karol S. but one question is bothering me that why it works when I insert but mess it up when I update? We are using hibernate can it be issue?

Comment: Perhaps. Are you logging SQL on the app side and/or on the DB side? Logs could shed some light.

Comment: Thanks Karol S i have identified the issue as we are caching before the db it was working fine till the memcache gets busted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To store emojis into a Mysql Database convert the string you are storing into an encoded Base 64 string. On your application side all you have to do is decode that string using Base 64.

Encoding

```
                byte[] data = editTextFieldWithEmojis.getText().toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                base64String = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Decoding

```
                byte[] data = Base64.decode(stringWithEmojis, Base64.DEFAULT);
                newStringWithEmojis = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```