# finding values case insensitively with emojis

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with varchar value that needs to store text values with emojis:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `value_idx` (`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Now I need to do selects on this table to find all values starting with prefix. Selects must be case insensitive and must match emoji as well. So far I found 4 options, which all have trade offs:

1. I can use utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation and do selects like

   ```
   select * from my_table where value like 'prefix%'
   ```

   It will wind all values starting with prefix ignoring its characters case, but will not find anything if prefix contains emojis
2. I can set collection to utf8mb4_bin and my selects will find values if prefix contains emojis, but will be case sensitive
3. I can do

   ```
   select * from my_table where LOWER(value) like 'prefix%'
   ```

   and it will work case insensitively and with emojis, but will not use index
4. And finally I can save all values in lower case and use utf8mb4_bin collation, but saving in lower case is also the trade off

Is there any solution that would allow me to do "like" selects ignoring case of the prefix and allowing to have emojis in prefix?

UPD: I do not have problems with storing emojis, I have problems with finding them with "like" select keeping case insensitive collation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Android Emoji in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684739/storing-android-emoji-in-mysql)

Comment: absolutely not, that question is about problems with storing emojis. I don't have such problems because I use utf8mb4 which is able to store 4 bytes unicode characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use MySQL 5.6+ and to use utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci collation which doesn't treat all 4 bytes characters as equal