# Sequelize: Emoji in where returns wrong record

Tags: mysql, unicode, discord.js, sequelize.js, emoji

I have an utf8mb4 table, with 4 records.

When I use this select:

```
await database.Roles.findOne({
    where: {
        messageId: messageId,
        type: 'REACTION',
        reaction: reaction,
    },
});
```

For the given `messageId` I have 4 records where the `reaction` is
:yellow_circle: :blue_circle: :red_circle: :green_circle: in this order

I can query any of these emojis, but somewhy the output is always the one with the :yellow_circle:

Why? What can be the problem here?

**Update**

Blue query:

```
SELECT `id`, `guildId`, `type`, `roleId`, `messageId`, `reactionId`, `oneRole`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` 
FROM `Roles` AS `Roles` 
WHERE `Roles`.`guildId` = '844213646163050496' 
AND `Roles`.`messageId` = '855360336462217246' 
AND `Roles`.`type` = 'REACTION' 
AND `Roles`.`reaction` = '' 
LIMIT 1;
```

Yellow query:

```
SELECT `id`, `guildId`, `type`, `roleId`, `messageId`, `reactionId`, `oneRole`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` 
FROM `Roles` AS `Roles` 
WHERE `Roles`.`guildId` = '844213646163050496' 
AND `Roles`.`messageId` = '855360336462217246' 
AND `Roles`.`type` = 'REACTION' 
AND `Roles`.`reaction` = '' 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Does `Roles` has 4 records with same `messageId`?

`findOne` is the function to fetch 1 record from `Roles` that match the `where` condition.  If you need all records, you need to use `findAll`.

Comment: Yes, the `messageId` is same for the 4 records. I only need the record with the proper `messageId` and `reaction` combination, but if I query for :blue_circle: the output is for :yellow_circle:

Comment: I see. Could you post the generated SQL for both when you query for yellow and also for blue?

Comment: @Emma updated the question with the queries

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce. The query looks right.  Maybe adding the model definition here could help.

Comment: I ran the query in MySQL-cli without the limit statement and it returned all four rows, so as it seems that the problem is with my MySQL server.

Comment: Possibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/41147829/5320906?

Comment: So perhaps `select ... collate 'utf8mb4_bin';` will work?

Comment: Thank you, the whole db was `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and after I've changed the table to `utf8mb4_bin` it works :)

Comment: `SELECT '' = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; ` gives "1" meaning "equal" for that collation.  After that old collation, these circles became not equal.  Try that with `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` .